# dotNet MAUI Shell - Add Flyout Item in C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-maui

I have an old App I wrote years ago in Xamarin and looking to update it to MAUI, and not a huge fan of writing Xaml.

I know you can render pages with straight code, so I thought I would try this with Shell as well, but can't figure out the correct context for adding flyout items.

Even the slightest attempt like the below causes unhandled win32 errors:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        Items.Add(new FlyoutItem
        {
            Title = "test"
        });
    }
}
```

So I'm obviously going about it the wrong way.  What is the correct syntax?

[image]

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to be the flyoutitem. Just the pure fact that there isn't a Xaml form that goes with it seems to break it. I can have the xaml with just a single tab bar element and it won't crash. But the flyout item won't render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out myself.  I found this page which put me onto the right path: https://gist.github.com/TheBaileyBrew/f8a9d2e4668da3ec9bff9bf86d32d951

Anyway, so basically I was able to create an XAMLess AppShell.cs with essentially only this and it created the Shell instance, no problem.

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));

        Items.Add(new FlyoutItem
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Route = x.Route,
            Icon = new FontImageSource
            {
                FontFamily = "fasolid900",
                Glyph = FontAwesome.FontAwesomeIcons.Home,
            },
            Items =
            {
                new Tab{
                    Title = "Home",
                    Items = {
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Home",
                            Route = nameof(MainPage),
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MainPage))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As I figured it out is that it doesn't have to be XAMLess AppShell. To create a `FlyoutItem` via `Items.Add` you have to add `Items` to `new FlyoutItem` and it has to be populated with at least one `ShellContent` object. Otherwise the `FlyoutItem` won't be shown in the flyout. Nonetheless your self-answered question brought me to right track as I was troubling with the same issue in my app. Many thanks:)

Comment: Thanks for this. I too am converting a Xamarin app over to MAUI and its a bit like pulling teeth :)